# K8s Ingress to Static Assets in DigitalOcean Bucket

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to use an `Ingress` and `ExternalName` Service in Kubernetes to route traffic to an external storage service (DigitalOcean Spaces) - but no matter what I try, I get some form of http error.

Things I've tried:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/629#issue-116679227 (Error: 404 Not Found, nginx)
- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1809 (Error: 502 Bad Gateway, nginx)
- A fair bit of other tinkering which has been lost to time.

How do I configure a K8s Ingress/Service to direct ingress requests from `example.com/static` to a storage bucket (e.g. `<zone>.digitaloceanspaces.com/<bucket-name>/<path>/<object>`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of the resources I was able to find were simply outdated. The following solution works as of Kubernetes v1.21.4.

**Important Notes**:

- All `Ingress` annotations are *required*:

  - `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` - necessary to engage Nginx ingress controller.
  - `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS` - necessary to maintain HTTPS traffic to service ([this replaces `/secure-backends` in older versions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#backend-protocol)).
  - `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost` - must match service `externalName`, removes hostname from request path (e.g. if this is missing and being tested through localhost, will likely encounter error: "No such bucket: localhost").
  - `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` - passes matched asset URL path through to service.
- The `path.service.port.number` in the Ingress definition must match whatever port the `ExternalName` service expects (443 in the case of our HTTPS traffic).

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: do-bucket-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: <zone>.digitaloceanspaces.com

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: do-bucket-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /<bucket>/$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: <zone>.digitaloceanspaces.com
spec:
  rules:
  - http: 
      paths:
      - path: /path/to/static/assets(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: do-bucket-service
            port:
              number: 443
```